# Is there anyway to debugging .NET Core source code by Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

Due to Visual studio too large for me, I just wondering can I get a way to debugging .NET Core source code by Visual Studio Code?

By reading offical documents, it seems I can debug .NET Core source code by Visual Studio 2017 on Windowss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be possible. At the beginning of VS Code, debugging works first on MAC and Linux :) 
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging 
- https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger.md