# How to debug dotnet core source code using Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I would like to explore the source code of dotnet when debugging my application, for example. I would like to hit `F11` on the `Where` Linq method and see step by step what is happening at runtime.

I am aware that this is possible using Visual Studio (https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/897), and in Rider it is enabled by default, and stepping into it is as easy as debugging my own code.

What it the easiest way to set this up in visual studio code and is it even possible?

Please note, this is NOT a duplicate of [Is there anyway to debugging .NET Core source code by Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45474228/is-there-anyway-to-debugging-net-core-source-code-by-visual-studio-code) as that is regarding simple debugging in VSCode, not stepping into the BCL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
Two links that were already mentioned by you are valuable but there is one more link https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md

First, check 'launch.json' configuration file

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "example name",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/app/bin/Debug/net6.0/app.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "justMyCode": false, // should be false, as we want to debug 3rd party source code
            "requireExactSource": false, // https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#require-exact-source
            "suppressJITOptimizations": true, // it's better to set true for local debugging
            "enableStepFiltering": false, // to step into properties
            "symbolOptions": {
                "searchMicrosoftSymbolServer": true, // get pdb files from ms symbol server
                "searchNuGetOrgSymbolServer": true,
                "moduleFilter": {
                    "mode": "loadAllButExcluded",
                    "excludedModules": []
                }
            },
            "logging": { // you can delete it if all is ok
                "moduleLoad": true,
                "engineLogging": true,
                "trace": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After you start debugging the '`DEBUG CONSOLE`' will contain log like this

```
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.10\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.10\System.Console.dll'. Symbols loaded.
```

If there was a problem with loading some pdbs you can use [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/decompiler/), as local symbol server.

After that you can use '`Step Into (F11)`' button in debug panel at vscode to debug .net source code.

Comment: This is great stuff. Not as easy to use as Rider, but it definitely lets exploring more available.

Comment: It does miss out many steps though. A single F10 can skip loads of calls, but still good