# How to debug a dll for a third-party application in visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, dll

I'm quite new to VS Code. I have been debugging DLLs for 3rd party applications earlier in Visual Studio but it seems all the tools available there are not available in VS Code.

What I have been doing in VS earlier is:

- create, develop and build my DLL to the plugins folder of that 3rd application (with references to the 3rd party application's libraries)
- add the 3rd party exe as another project and set it as startup project.
- when starting debugging session, VS automatically launches/attaches to my dll, i.e. I can step through my code when I start the plugin inside the app.

I am able to successfully build the DLL in VS Code to the correct folder and it works (will show me the simple msgbox i am waiting for). However, when I try to debug it by attaching the debugger to the 3rd party app process, the debugger does not stop at the breakpoints. When I hover over the breakpoint during debugging (which is not red anymore during debug), I get the message "No symbols loaded for this document". I guess I'm doing something wrong. The .pdb for the DLL is in that plugins directory. Is this because the debugger does not find it? Honestly, I'm not very well in with the launch.json contents yet (no need to work with those in full VS). What is the best way (if any) to do this kind of debugging in VS Code? In case this is something that definitely can't be done in VS Code, please let me know, so I know I need to return back to full IDE.

Comment: Maybe this other question can help : [How to debug dotnet core source code using Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72601702/how-to-debug-dotnet-core-source-code-using-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I just had some issues in my launch.json. I am now able to step through my code and the UX is practically the same than that with full VS. Problem solved.

@vernou Thanks for the link anyway!